# I need some help on validating the below code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to validate the below code in js so that the user has to check one but i do not know how to. The form name is 'registration'

```html
<li>
   <input type="checkbox" name="en" value="en"  />
   <span>English</span>
</li>
<li>
   <input type="checkbox" name="nonen" value="noen" />
   <span>Non English</span>
</li>
```

Comment: need to show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 7):

Use an input of type radio instead.
Here is a link to the MDN documentation, basically all inputs of type `radio` that have the same `name` property are grouped together and the user can select only one of them.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 3):

You could try this one

```html
<input type="radio" name="raden" id="english" checked>
<label for="english">English</label>
<input type="radio" name="radnon" id="nonenglish">
<label for="nonenglish">Non-English</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="en" value="en"  /><span>English</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="en" value="en" /><span>Non English</span></li>
```

In check box name  must be same if all check boxes are selected. Try thid code.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<li>
 <input type="radio" name="nonen" value="en" checked/>
 <span>English</span>
</li>
<li>
 <input type="radio" name="nonen" value="noen"/>
 <span>Non English</span>
```

```
<li>
 <input type="radio" name="nonen" value="en" checked/>
 <span>English</span>
</li>
<li>
 <input type="radio" name="nonen" value="noen"/>
 <span>Non English</span>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding some explanation to it. [Read this article] on how to write a good answer.